# several map and reduce functions in a M/R program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, nosql, cassandra

I have a question. can we have several map and reduce functions in a cassandra mapreduce program? for example map1 reads the data and reduce1 groups them by keys. map2 calculate average and map3 Math.pow for the result and finally the reduce function write the output? or something like this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is common practice to "chain jobs". All you basically do is have the first mapreduce job write out to HDFS, then the second mapreduce job reads the output from the first job as its input.

This [tutorial is a useful start](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#chaining).

---

Not answering your question, but....

Calculate the average in reducer 1. Can you also do `Math.pow` in reducer 1 as well after calculating the average? All it is java code, so write the calculations in the reduce function.

Another note, you don't need a reducer to output. Mappers can output data too, just set the number of reducers to 0.

Comment: thanks Donald. your answer was so clear and also thanks for the Link.. it was so helpful..